# Haskell: Combining existential and universal quantifiers fails unexpectedly

Tags: haskell, ghc, existential-type, functional-logic-progr

I am trying to model the following logical implication in Haskell with GHC, version 8.6.5:

(∀ a. ¬ Φ(a)) →  ¬ (∃ a: Φ(a))

The definitions I used are the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, GADTs #-}

import Data.Void

-- Existential quantification via GADT
data Ex phi where
  Ex :: forall a phi. phi a -> Ex phi

-- Universal quantification, wrapped into a newtype
newtype All phi = All (forall a. phi a)

-- Negation, as a function to Void
type Not a = a -> Void

-- Negation of a predicate, wrapped into a newtype
newtype NotPred phi a = NP (phi a -> Void)

-- The following definition does not work:
theorem :: All (NotPred phi) -> Not (Ex phi)
theorem (All (NP f)) (Ex a) = f a
```

Here, GHC rejects the implementation of the `theorem` with the following error message:

```
* Couldn't match type `a' with `a0'
  `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
    a pattern with constructor:
      Ex :: forall a (phi :: * -> *). phi a -> Ex phi,
    in an equation for `theorem'
    at question.hs:20:23-26
* In the first argument of `f', namely `a'
  In the expression: f a
  In an equation for `theorem': theorem (All (NP f)) (Ex a) = f a
* Relevant bindings include
    a :: phi a (bound at question.hs:20:26)
    f :: phi a0 -> Void (bound at question.hs:20:18)
```

I do not really understand why GHC shouldn't be able to match the two types.
The following workaround compiles:

```
theorem = flip theorem' where
    theorem' (Ex a) (All (NP f)) = f a
```

To me, the two implementations of `theorem` are equivalent. Why does GHC only accept the second one?

Comment: That's weird. Looks like GHC needs to know which type to instantiate `a` to _at the point where it unpacks_ the `All` constructor. But that shouldn't actually be necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you match the pattern `All prf` against a value of type `All phi`, `prf` is extracted as a polymorphic entity of type `forall a. phi a`. In this case, you get a `no :: forall a. NotPred phi a`. However, you cannot perform pattern matching on an object of this type. After all, it's a function from types to values. You need to apply it to a specific type (call it `_a`), and you'll get `no @_a :: NotPred phi _a`, which now can be matched to extract a `f :: phi _a -> Void`. If you expand your definition...

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
-- type signature with forall needed to bind the variable phi
theorem :: forall phi. All (NotPred phi) -> Not (Ex phi)
theorem prf wit = case prf of
    All no -> case no @_a of -- no :: forall a. NotPred phi a
        NP f -> case wit of -- f :: phi _a -> Void
            Ex (x :: phi b) -> f x -- matching against Ex extracts a type variable, call it b, and then x :: phi b
```

So the question is, what type should be used for `_a`? Well, we are applying `f :: phi _a -> Void` to `x :: b` (where `b` is the type variable stored in `wit`), so we should set `_a := b`. But this is a scoping violation. `b` is only extracted by matching against `Ex`, which happens after we've specialized `no` and extracted `f`, so `f`'s type cannot depend on `b`. Thus, there's no choice of `_a` that can make this work without letting the existential variable escape its scope. Error.

The solution, as you've discovered, is to match against `Ex` (thus extracting the type inside it) before applying that type to `no`.

```
theorem :: forall phi. All (NotPred phi) -> Not (Ex phi)
theorem prf wit = case wit of
    Ex (x :: phi b) -> case prf of
        All no -> case no @b of
            NP f -> f x
-- or
theorem :: forall phi. All (NotPred phi) -> Not (Ex phi)
theorem (All no) (Ex x) | NP f <- no = f x
```

Comment: So the point is that `no :: forall a. NotPred phi a` cannot be pattern-matched to `f :: forall a. phi a -> Void` despite `NotPred` is just a newtype?

Comment: Yep. You can write a function for the conversion, but the constructor `NP` only accepts `NotPred phi a`s, not `forall a. NotPred phi a`. I would suggest giving `NP` a record field—`newtype NotPred phi a = NotPred { unNotPred :: phi a -> Void }`—and writing `theorem (All no) (Ex x) = unNotPred no x`.